# OpenShift socket.io : express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env')

Tags: node.js, sockets, openshift

After setting client and server side of socket.io, what I think are the right links, now something else sprung up.

My assumption is - I am using an old express version or one that is too new for the code I have?

```
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0 
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js' Tue, 29 Jul 2014 13:51:04 GMT express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement at server.js:11:5 info: socket.io started warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES 
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0 
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js' Tue, 29 Jul 2014 13:51:06 GMT express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement at server.js:11:5 info: socket.io started warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES
```

Any guidance?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to listen on listen on the wrong ip /port.  Can you show some of your code around that line that causes the error?

Comment: server.js: var PORT = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080; 
var IPADDRESS = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
console.log(">PORT>"+ PORT + ">IP>" + IPADDRESS);
// PORT
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, IPADDRESS);



// Create a Socket.IO server and attach it to the http server
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

Comment: index.html : <script src='ws://socketoslive-multisockettest.rhcloud.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>

Comment: socket.js : var socket = io.connect('ws://socketoslive-multisockettest.rhcloud.com:8000');

Answer (score 4):

For the deprecated function `app.configure` just use `app.use` without using `app.configure`, and for the error `Error: listen EACCES` check if you have anything listening in the port you are trying to start your `server.js`

Comment: yes that works. replace app.configure(function () {..   for app.use(function ()  thanks{